# Creating a list of lists with regular expressions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nsregularexpression

I thought I had successfully created and filtered a list of lists using regular expression in python. However, when I attempt to index the lists I just index the first item in each of the lists. Upon closer inspection I noticed that I don't have any commas between my lists. I'm wondering how I can turn each of these individual lists into a list of lists?

I want to do this so that I can reference the different lists and state whether the lists meets a specific criteria.

```
import re



 list_of_strings = ['''<z><x><c></v></b></n>''',
 '''<paa>mnb<ore>mnbczx</bar><e>poiuy</e></paa>''',
 '''<paa><ore></lan></ore></paa>''',
 '''<paa><ore></ore></paa></paa>''',
 '''<paa><ore></paa></ore>''']
def valid_html(list_of_strings):
    matches = [[s] for s in list_of_strings]
    lst = []
    for item in matches:
        tagsRegex = re.compile(r'(<.{0,3}>|</.{0,3}>)')
        lst = (tagsRegex.findall(str(item)))
        find = re.compile(r'(<)|(>)')
        no_tags = [find.sub('', t) for t in lst]
        print(no_tags)
        print(no_tags[0])
valid_html(test_strings)
```

My output is:

```
valid_html(test_strings)
['z', 'x', 'c', '/v', '/b', '/n']
z
['paa', 'ore', '/ore', 'e', '/e', '/paa']
paa
['paa', 'ore', '/lan', '/ore', '/paa']
paa
['paa', 'ore', '/ore', '/paa', '/paa']
paa
['paa', 'ore', '/paa', '/ore']
paa
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is your _expected_ output?

Comment: ['z', 'x', 'c', '/v', '/b', '/n']

Comment: How is it different from the output that is included in your post?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. print(no_tags[0]) should return ['z', 'x', 'c', '/v', '/b', '/n']. Right now it returns the first item from each list.

Comment: You must be confusing `print` and `return`.  Read about the difference and decide whether you want to _print_ the result or _return_ it. At the moment, you print both the list and the first item, and return nothing. You are getting exactly what you are asking for,

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting inside the loop and printing inside the loop. You need to print outside the for loop of need to return the same

```
def valid_html(list_of_strings):
    matches = [[s] for s in list_of_strings]
    lst = []
    l=[]
    for item in matches:
        tagsRegex = re.compile(r'(<.{0,3}>|</.{0,3}>)')
        lst = (tagsRegex.findall(str(item)))
        find = re.compile(r'(<)|(>)')
        no_tags = [find.sub('', t) for t in lst]
        l.append(no_tags)
    return l
valid_html(list_of_strings)[0]
```

Comment: If the OP follows your advice, only the last result will be printed.

Comment: @DYZ Edited the post

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for the help.